# Risk factors for derivatives on dividends

Tags: equities, derivatives, risk-models, dividends

I consider pricing and risk analysis of derivatives on dividends of the members of equity indices (such as Dow Jones EuroStoxx). There are options but I focus on futures.

1. What are the main risk factors for dividends?
2. Which quantitative factors do you consider in the context of derivatives on dividends?

I found a nice presentation by [Bühler of JPMorgan](http://www.quantitative-research.de/dl/ModellingDividends.pdf) but who has further references, experiences, comments?

Note that stochastic models for derivatives on dividends are covered in [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7625/stochastic-modelling-of-derivatives-on-dividends).

Comment: does anyone have a link to the buhler presentation? the one in this question is dead

Comment: It *might* be this one https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1706758